# Pytorch running_mean, running_var and num_batches_tracked are updated during training, but I want to fix them

Tags: python, pytorch, pre-trained-model, batch-normalization

In pytorch, I want to use a pretrained model and train my model to add a delta to the model result, that is:

```
        ╭----- (pretrained model) ------ result ---╮
 input------------- (my model) --------- Δresult --+-- final_result
```

Here is what I did:

1. Use `load_state_dict` to load pretrained model's parameters
2. Set all pretrained model's parameters `requires_grad = False`
3. Create my model and start training

But after training process, when I check `result` (the output of pretrained model), I find that it does not match the origin pretrained model output. I carefully compare the pretrained model's parameters, the only change are `BatchNorm2d` 's `running_mean`, `running_var` and `num_batches_tracked` (since I set all pretrained model's parameters `requires_grad = False`) , and when I change these three parameters back to origin ones, the `result` matches the origin pretrained model output.

I do not want any change in pretrained model. So is there any way to fix `running_mean`, `running_var` and `num_batches_tracked`?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem, so I adapted the context manager found in [this repo](https://github.com/giladcohen/VAT_pytorch/blob/master/vat.py) as follows:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def _disable_tracking_bn_stats(self):
    def switch_attr():
        if not hasattr(self, 'running_stats_modules'):
            self.running_stats_modules = \
                [mod for n, mod in self.model.named_modules() if
                 hasattr(mod, 'track_running_stats')]

        for mod in self.running_stats_modules:
            mod.track_running_stats ^= True

    switch_attr()
    yield
    switch_attr()
```

As an alternative, I think you can obtain a similar result by calling `eval` on the BatchNorm modules:

```
for layer in net.modules():
    if isinstance(layer, BatchNorm2d):
        layer.eval()
```

though the first method is more principled.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I solve my problem!

Comment: Then please, mark the answer as correct :)